# Alexa sent multiple request to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm building the Alexa skill that sends the request to my web server,
then web server will do some process and upload a file to Amazon S3.
During the period of web server process, I make skill keep getting the file from Amazon S3 per 10 seconds till get the file. And the response is based on the file content.

But unfortunately, the web server process takes more than 1 minute. That means skill must stay more than 1 minute to get the file to response.

For now, I used progressive response with async await in my code,
and skill did keep waiting for the file on S3.
But I found that the skill will send the second request to Lambda after 50 seconds automatically. That means for the same skill, i got the two lambda function running at the same time.

And the execution result is :  After the first response that progressive response made, 50 seconds later will hear another response that also made by the progressive response which belongs to the second request.
And nothing happened till the end.

I know it is bad to let skill waits this long, but i still want to figure out the executable way if skill needs to wait this long.

There are some points I want to figure out.

1. Is there anyway to prevent the skill to send the second
   requests to Lambda?
2. Is there another way I can try to accomplish the goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found that the second invoke of Lambda is not from Alexa, is from AWS Lambda itself. Refer to the following artical

https://cloudonaut.io/your-lambda-function-might-execute-twice-deal-with-it/

So you have to deal with this kind of situation in your Lambda code. One thing can be used is these two times invoke's request id is the same. So you can tell if this is the first time execution by checking your storage for the same request id which you store at the first time execution.

Besides, I also found that once the Alexa Skill waits for more than 1 minutes, it will crash and return the error by speaking (test by Amazon Echo). And there is nothing different in the AWS Lambda log compare to the normal execution one. That meaning the Log  seems to be fine but actually the execution result is not.

Hope this can help someone is also struggled at this problem.